# nodejs/selenium webdriver: Can't move mouse to a required position

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having trouble in moving mouse pointer in chrome webdriver to a required position in nodejs. I'm using `-selenium webdriver 4.0.0-alpha.1`.

This is how i'm building the driver

```js
const {Builder,By} = require("selenium-webdriver");
let driver = new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
```

This is where i'm defining the logic to move mouse to a position named `value = { x: 262, y: 315 }`

```js
await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.className("OUeyt")));
let a = driver.findElement(By.className("_3Bxar"));
let actions = driver.actions({bridge: true});
await actions.mouseMove(a, value).click().perform();
```

Whenever i run this part, it says `mousemove()` is not a function. I've tried what the docs say to no avail. On stackoverflow, the solutions are present but for Java and i HAVE to do it in JavaScript. What can i do to perform this functionality?

Answer (score 3):

`driver.action().mouseMove()` was deprecated in **v4.0.0-alpha1**. Check out this link: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/input_exports_Actions.html

Comment: `await driver
    .actions()
    .move({ origin: deleteButton })
    .perform();` keeps timing out. And, yes `deleteButton` is a thing on the screen as it passes other tests. However, I can't get it into a 'hover' state to test that. :(

Answer (score 0):

`mouseMove()` in actions api of latest version of *selenium-webdriver* is depricated for chrome. You can revert back to **version 3.6.0** if you still want to use it.

As alternatives, you can use execute/executeScript or directly from [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/input_exports_Actions.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help buddy. Can you tell me how to do this by executeScript/execute?